# Need to search specific data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search specific data from one column and check if it is in another column.

For example, I have in one column `paul.gene` and in another column, I have emails and I need to check if there is an email that starts with `paul.gene@stsdq.pl`. I tried to use match, search, lookup but they are not giving me good answers that I have checked manually.

I tried to use `(MATCH("*"&B6&"*";E:E;1))` and it s not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try match like below-

```
=MATCH(A3&"*",D1:D10,0)
```

[image]

Comment: =if(countif(a:a,"*" & b2 & "*")>0,"YES","NO")
Thanks for help i finally did it this way, i will try yours